# Remove element in an iframe with jQuery

Tags: jquery, iframe

I'd like to remove an unnecessary header from a iframe webpage.  Solutions in other SO pages on this don't seems to work.  An example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Modifying iFrame element</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Let's remove the header toolbar (class "header")</p>
<iframe id="wikipedia" src="https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Ben" onload="removeHead()" style="width: 800; height: 500;"></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">

function removeHead(){
    $(function(){
        var f=$('#wikipedia');
        f.load(function(){ 
             f.contents().find('.header').hide();
        });
    });
    console.log("script complete");
};

</script>>
</body>
</html>
```

The script runs but nothing happens.  I've tried using remove() instead of hide(), and other combinations, with no luck.  Grateful for assistance.

Comment: You don't have access to wikipedia, and you can't change it's content, not even in an iFrame as it's subject to the same-origin policy.

Comment: You cannot manipulate with pages cross domain.

Comment: you can't edit iframe data if it isn't in your domain...

Comment: @adeneo I don't have access to wikipedia and I **can** change it's content if it's not in an iframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to browser security, content cannot generally be accessed using or manipulated from within an iframe unless it is on the same domain.  This may not be the case with some older browsers, but definitely is now.

This is regulated by the [Same-origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

Also see this article: http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/iframes/refs/iframe.php

> Note: These cross-document interactions are only possible if the documents have the same origin.

**Possible Solution 1**

Use [PHP Simple DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to get a specific div element, or certain portion of the page:

```
include("./dom/simple_html_dom.php");

$html = file_get_html("https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Ben");
$content = $html->find("#content", 0);

echo $content->innertext;
```

Which will yield this: http://bibletools.info/script/wikipedia.php

**Possible Solution 2**

Use [PHP Simple DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to simply remove the header.  If you create a separate PHP page and load that php page into an iframe you'll not have conflicting styles etc.

```
include("./dom/simple_html_dom.php");

$html = file_get_html("https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Ben");

$html->find('div.header', 0)->outertext = '';
$html->find('.top-bar', 0)->outertext = '';

echo $html;
```

Which will yield this: http://bibletools.info/script/wikipedia1.php

NOTE: This solution may be slightly slow, because the server must first load the page, then serve it to the user.  However, practically it is quite efficient.  I use this method all the time with great success.

Comment: @geotheory your best solution will be to use PHP and the PHP DOM Parser, it's quite simple to use, and you can select the content of a certain element and format it as desired on your page. http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: If you like I can add an example to my answer.

Comment: Sorry, should have explained. You need to download the Simple PHP DOM parser. It includes that file, along with many others. Once you link to it as I have shown, the code should work.

Comment: OK I've cracked it!  Thanks Adam that's most helpful